# How to initialize the rest of an object after a for loop in TypeScript/Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, oop, typescript

I'm just a bit confused right now. Is there a clean way to initialize some of the properties of an object in a for loop and the remaining properties right after that loop?

My interface looks like this:

```
export interface ExampleOptions {
    propOne: string;
    proTwo: number;
    probThree: number;
    propFour: string;
}
```

Inside my Component I do something like this:

```
  exampleOptions: ExampleOptions[] = [];

  ngOnChanges() {
    if (someConditions) {
      for (let index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
        this.exampleOptions[index] = {
          propOne: string;
          proTwo: number;
        };
      }
      // TODO: Initialize rest of the object here
      this.exampleOptions {
        propThree: number;
        propFour: string;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Why don't you do it in the loop itself?

Comment: Because the first to properties (propOne, propTwo) has to be in a loop to generate something and the rest of the properties have only one value.

Comment: **'Rest of the properties'** with same value for every element in the array?

Comment: No, the rest of the object properties have individual values that get set in other methods.

Comment: From where do you get the values for `propOne` and `propTwo`? Are you missing something in your question? You can't assign string and number as values for them and those semi-colons won't go up there.

Comment: By the way that expression `this.exampleOptions[index]= {..}` will throw an error since `propThree` and `propFour` are missing.

Comment: I think you need to be more specific what you are trying to do, what you have tried, and what issues you encountered